# Parse twitter followers api

Tags: php, twitter

How to get the screen's name of the follower from the twitter's API?

```
array(200) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (46) { ["id"]=> int(14763734) ["id_str"]=> string(8) "14763734" ["name"]=> string(14) "Digital Trends" ["screen_name"]=> string(13) "DigitalTrends"
```

Here is my code using Abraham's API

```
$row = $connection->get("followers/list", ["screen_name" => 
$influencer, "count" => '200', "skip_status"=>1]);

foreach($row as $data){
 $handle = $data['screen_name'];
//
// echo "$handle <br /><br />";
//var_dump($data);
```

}

I've tried

```
$row = json_decode($row, true);
```

And tried

```
$data->screen_name;
```

Nothing seems to work... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($data);` inside foreach?let me know

Comment: it's the 1st part of the post
array(200) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (46) { ["id"]=> int(14763734) ["id_str"]=> string(8) "14763734" ["name"]=> string(14) "Digital Trends" ["screen_name"]=> string(13) "DigitalTrends" ... etc

Comment: Just to clarify, did you try `$data->screen_name;` in your foreach loop? edit: Seems like Alive to Die is on the right track. For some reason $data isn't containing one row. It still has the whole array in it.

Comment: means $data hae 200 entries there?

Comment: I added it to pastebin  https://pastebin.com/LwMP79T5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below for one data:-

```
foreach($row as $data){
 $handle = $data[0]->screen_name;
  echo "$handle <br /><br />";
}
```

for all:-

```
foreach($row as $data){
  foreach($data as $dat){
     $handle = $dat->screen_name;
     echo "$handle <br /><br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks... that worked but it's only returning the 1st item in the array